# How can I raise a number to power in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Please what is the simplest method to exponentiate a number
Cus I don't see it in the javascript arithematic operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Math.pow(base, exponent)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/pow) is the answer.

```js
console.log(Math.pow(4, 3)) // 64
```

In addition, newer browers <sup>[quotation needed]</sup> supports the `**` operation:

```js
console.log(4 ** 3) // 64
```

If you want to test if your current browser supports it simply click on "Run code snippet". If you see `64`, congratulations! It works.